# Modify an existing word table using c#

Tags: c#

I need to open an existing word document(*.doc) with an existing table(for example 5 columns and 1 rows).Then i want add data from another table (rows are dynamic) or database. Can you help me please i'm just began learning c#

Thanks you

Here is my code

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;

using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;



namespace AjouterTableau
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

  DataTable table = new DataTable();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //add columns
        table.Columns.Add("Objet de la facturation", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Quantité", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("PU ou Base", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Taux", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Montant", typeof(string));


        //add rows
        table.Rows.Add("Dev", 2, 100,20,1500);
        table.Rows.Add("formation", 10, 100,30,1500);
        table.Rows.Add("conseil", 3, 200,40,2000);
        table.Rows.Add("Dev", 0, 300,20,1500);
        table.Rows.Add("conseil", 0, 400,40,2000);
    }

    private void createInvoice(object fileName, object saveAs)
    {

        //Connexion to word
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = true;
        object savechanges = true;

        object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";

        //create a reference for optionals parameters
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //create word document
        Word.Document wordDoc=null;
        Word.Table tables = null;

        //test whether there is a new document or an existing document
        if (System.IO.File.Exists((string)fileName))
        {

                object readOnly = false;
                object isVisible = true;

            //Open existing document
            wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            //active document
            wordDoc.Activate();


            int i=0;
            int j=0;
            Word.Tables table = wordDoc.Tables;
            if (table.Count>0)
            {
                //retreive the first table of the document
                tables = table[1];

                for (i=1; i <tables.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
                    {
                        // i want to replace text with this method
                        FindAndReplace()
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("file not found");
            return;
        }



        //save document
        wordDoc.SaveAs(ref saveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        //close document
        wordDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


        //close word
        wordApp.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    }

    private void FindAndReplace(Word.Application WordApp,
                                 object findText,
                                 object replaceWithText)
    {
        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundsLike = false;
        object nmatchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;

        WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
            ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike,
            ref nmatchAllWordForms, ref forward,
            ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
            ref replace, ref matchKashida,
            ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza,
            ref matchControl);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       createInvoice(@"c:\temp\template2.doc", @"c:\temp\facture.doc");

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.  As an aside, from C# 4 the 'missing' parameters are not required as they are optional.  Your document open can be written as `wordApp.Documents.Open(filename)`, for example.

Comment: @CharlesMager...thanks you for your quick reply.

I have a empty table in word document as a template (for example: 2 rows and 5 columns). 
i would like to populate it from the table "table" in "Form1" constructor.
But i don't know how to do it